# How to extract first word from DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dataset, kaggle

### Background

I have created the below data frame combining two dataset from Kaggle.

[Titanic: Machine Learning from Disaster](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic)
（input/titanic/train.csv）

[titanic-nationalities](https://www.kaggle.com/reppic/titanic-nationalities)

DataFrame name: output

```
    PassengerId Nationality Name
0   1   CelticEnglish   Braund, Mr. Owen Harris
1   2   CelticEnglish   Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Th...
2   3   Nordic,Scandinavian,Sweden  Heikkinen, Miss. Laina
3   4   CelticEnglish   Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel
....
```

What I hoped to transform

```
    PassengerId Nationality Name
0   1   CelticEnglish   Braund
1   2   CelticEnglish   Cumings
2   3   Nordic  Heikkinen
3   4   CelticEnglish   Futrelle
....
```

### Problem

I tried to execute the below code, but I have no idea to fix the below.

Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
----> 1 output['Nationality'].split('\n', 1)[0]
      2 output['Name'].split('\n', 1)[0]

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5137             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5138                 return self[name]
-> 5139             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5140 
   5141     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'
```

### Code

```
output['Nationality'].split('\n', 1)[0]
output['Name'].split('\n', 1)[0]
```

### What I tried to do

I tried to change the type conversion, but the result was not changed.

```
output['Nationality'] = output['Nationality'].astype(str)
output['Name'] = output['Name'].astype(str)

output['Nationality'] = output['Nationality'].str.split('\n', expand=True)[0]
output['Name'] = output['Name'].str.split('\n', expand=True)[0]
output
```

```
PassengerId Nationality Name
0   1   CelticEnglish   Braund, Mr. Owen Harris
1   2   CelticEnglish   Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Th...
2   3   Nordic,Scandinavian,Sweden  Heikkinen, Miss. Laina
3   4   CelticEnglish   Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)
```

### Environment

Kaggle Notebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Series object doesn't have a split method. You're trying to split a string so you'll need to convert the column datatype into string first (or expand the column out into multiple columns) before applying a split.

check data type of columns with `df.dtypes`

assign datatype with `output['Nationality'].astype(str)`

edit: no parentheses on dtype call

Comment: I tried to check the datatype, but it returned `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'`.

Comment: sorry, no parentheses then and add an 's'https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't work like the above added section on my question.

Comment: What are the data types you're getting for the output dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `.str.split()`

```
output['Nationality'] = output['Nationality'].str.split('\n', expand=True)[0]
output['Name'] = output['Name'].str.split('\n', expand=True)[0]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't work like the above added section on my question.